# P4Python p4.temp_client broken?

Tags: python, c++, perforce

I can't seem to use the temp client with p4python...

When I save a client, I'm able to sync just fine.
Ex.

```
from P4 import P4,P4Exception
p4 = P4()
p4.client = "example"
p4.port = "1666"
p4.user = "fooser"
client_root = '/foo/bar'

p4.connect()
client = p4.fetch_client()
client._root = client_root
p4.save_client(p4)
p4.run_sync('-f')
```

Works fine. I get the file in my depot.

However if I tweak the last line to a temp client...

```
with p4.temp_client('temp',client) as t:
    p4.run_sync()
```

I get the below error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/fooser/repos/foo/foo-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/P4.py", line 868, in temp_client
    ws = self.fetch_client('-t', template, name)
  File "/Users/fooser/repos/foo/foo-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/P4.py", line 503, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kargs: self.__fetch(cmd, *args, **kargs)
  File "/Users/fooser/repos/foo/foo-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/P4.py", line 538, in __fetch
    result = self.run(cmd, "-o", *args, **kargs)
  File "/Users/fooser/repos/foo/foo-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/P4.py", line 611, in run
    raise e
  File "/Users/fooser/repos/foo/foo-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/P4.py", line 605, in run
        result = P4API.P4Adapter.run(self, *flatArgs)
P4.P4Exception: [P4#run] Errors during command execution( "p4 client -o -t {'Client': 'ansible', 'Update': '2018/09/20 05:58:44', 'Access': '2018/09/20 05:58:44', 'Owner': 'stobias', 'Host': 'toby-imac.local', 'Description': 'ignore', 'Root': '/Users/stobias/p4test', 'Options': 'noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime normdir', 'SubmitOptions': 'submitunchanged', 'LineEnd': 'local', 'Type': 'writeable', 'Backup': 'enable', 'View': ['//depot/... //ansible/...']} temp_9c5db5fa-bc9a-11e8-a517-10ddb1a3f3f1" )

    [Error]: "Wildcards (*, %%x, ...) not allowed in '{'Client':_'ansible',_'Update':_'2018/09/20_05:58:44',_'Access':_'2018/09/20_05:58:44',_'Owner':_'stobias',_'Host':_'toby-imac.local',_'Description':_'ignore',_'Root':_'/Users/stobias/p4test',_'Options':_'noallwrite_noclobber_nocompress_unlocked_nomodtime_normdir',_'SubmitOptions':_'submitunchanged',_'LineEnd':_'local',_'Type':_'writeable',_'Backup':_'enable',_'View':_['//depot/... //ansible/...']}'."
[P4#run] Errors during command execution( "p4 client -o -t {'Client': 'ansible', 'Update': '2018/09/20 05:58:44', 'Access': '2018/09/20 05:58:44', 'Owner': 'stobias', 'Host': 'toby-imac.local', 'Description': 'ignore', 'Root': '/Users/stobias/p4test', 'Options': 'noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime normdir', 'SubmitOptions': 'submitunchanged', 'LineEnd': 'local', 'Type': 'writeable', 'Backup': 'enable', 'View': ['//depot/... //ansible/...']} temp_9c5db5fa-bc9a-11e8-a517-10ddb1a3f3f1" )

    [Error]: "Wildcards (*, %%x, ...) not allowed in '{'Client':_'ansible',_'Update':_'2018/09/20_05:58:44',_'Access':_'2018/09/20_05:58:44',_'Owner':_'stobias',_'Host':_'toby-imac.local',_'Description':_'ignore',_'Root':_'/Users/stobias/p4test',_'Options':_'noallwrite_noclobber_nocompress_unlocked_nomodtime_normdir',_'SubmitOptions':_'submitunchanged',_'LineEnd':_'local',_'Type':_'writeable',_'Backup':_'enable',_'View':_['//depot/... //ansible/...']}'."
```

I tried to dig into the source a bit, but this library seems to rely on a c++ module and I'm way out of my depth there.

P4python source and examples - https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/view/guest/robert_cowham/perforce/API/python/index.html?v=9#downloads

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the error I can see that it's trying to pass a string representation of a Python dict as the "-t" flag to the p4 command, which is obviously wrong.  :)

From the doc on temp_client:

`p4.temp_client( "<prefix>", "<template>" )
Creates a temporary client, using the prefix <prefix> and based upon a client template named <template>`

The second arg is just the NAME of the template client (as a string), not the entire spec (as a dict).  That's the thing that'll be passed as the `-t template` in the actual p4 command.

Try:

```
with p4.temp_client('temp', 'example') as t:
    p4.run_sync()
```

Comment: Yes, the `temp_client` function looks like it wants to use an existing client as the template.  If you want to roll one from scratch, just skip that `temp_client` function and make your own client and delete it once you're done (which is really all `temp_client` is doing).

Comment: Mind if I ask what lines etc you found this info at? It was rather difficult for me to follow the flow of the program.

Comment: I googled "p4python temp_client".  Had never heard of it before (didn't use p4python very much as a Perforce user) but being familiar with Perforce it was easy to suss out what it was doing between the doc and your error message.  :)  https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/p4script/python.p4.html#python.p4.temp_client